# printf as argument of function

Tags: c, function, arguments, printf, argument-passing

Usually usage of function:

```
my_func("test");
```

Whether I can use this parameter so?

```
my_func(printf("current_count_%d",ad_id));
```

int my_func(const char *key)

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve. What is `my_func` intension?

Comment: sprintf of couse ... int my_func(const char *key)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use the return value of `printf` as a function parameter.
But remember `printf` on success returns the number of characters written.
So

```
foo(printf("bar%d",123));
```

passes `6` to the `foo` function not `bar123`.

If you want to pass the string that `printf` prints, you can make use of `sprintf` function. It is similar to `printf` but instead of writing to the console it writes into a char array.

Answer (score 4):

```
    char buf[64]; /* malloc or whatever */
    int pos = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "current_count_%d", ad_id);
    if (sizeof(buf) <= pos)
                    buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = '\0';
    my_func(buf)
```

Comment: Having done a quick bit of research, it's only on Windows that snprintf fails to add a terminating NULL if it truncates the output. So I wouldn't be surprised if this is a bug or side effect of Microsoft's disinterest in post-C89 developments.

Answer (score 2):

No; `printf()` returns the number of characters printed to stdout. Use `s[n]printf()` to create the string, then pass that.

Comment: Remember that you will have to manually declare a `char[] buffer` and release it when you're done with it.

Comment: Or just use an array of a statically declared length, like char buffer[50] or whatever.

Comment: That's right, because they're primitives, not objects. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to pass a variable number of arguments, like printf accepts, to some function then you need to look into . To reproduce printf (for the sake of argument):

```
void varargfunc(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char formattedString[2048]; /* fixed length, for a simple example - and
                                   snprintf will keep us safe anyway */
    va_list arguments;

    va_start(arguments, fmt); /* use the parameter before the ellipsis as
                                 a seed */

    /* assuming the first argument after fmt is known to be an integer,
       you could... */
    /*
        int firstArgument = va_arg(arguments, int);
        fprintf(stderr, "first argument was %d", firstArgument);
    */

    /* do an vsnprintf to get the formatted string with the variable
       argument list. The v[printf/sprintf/snprintf/etc] functions
       differ from [printf/sprintf/snprintf/etc] by taking a va_list
       rather than ... - a va_list can't turn back into a ... because
       it doesn't inherently know how many additional arguments it
       represents (amongst other reasons) */
    vsnprintf(formattedString, 2048, fmt, arguments);

    /* formattedString now contains the first 2048 characters of the
       output string, with correct field formatting and a terminating
       NULL, even if the real string would be more than 2047 characters
       long. So put that on stdout. puts adds an additional terminating
       newline character, so this varies a little from printf in that 
       regard. */
    puts(formattedString);

    va_end(arguments); /* clean up */
}
```

If you wanted to add additional arguments that aren't related to the format, add them before the 'fmt' argument. Fmt is passed to va_start to say "the variable arguments start after this one".

Answer (score 1):

The function `printf` [returns an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633367/what-is-the-signature-of-printf).

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Hence, you can use it in `my_func` as long as `my_func` takes an integer as parameter. This does not seem to be the case.