# what is the argument list in the printf() function?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the signature of printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633367/what-is-the-signature-of-printf)

I know that there will be an argument list for every function.
if we pass the arguments more than no.of variables mentioned in the argument list then
it gives an error.but my question is

Printf() function also has argument list and eventhough we give 'n' no.of arguments the 
printf() function doesnt fails then

i want to know wht will be used in argument list section of printf() which takes infinate argument list?

Comment: google "c variable number of arguments" and check out  `<stdarg.h>`

Comment: -1 *research effort*. StackOverflow is not a mechanical turk replacement for google. If you google your question title, you get the answer.

Comment: You can simply googled it before posting this question here!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printf's signature looks something like this:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

If a function has a '...' as its last argument, it can receive any number of arguments. Within the function, you would use va_arg to access those arguments. Here is an example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/):

```
/* va_start example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void PrintFloats ( int amount, ...)
{
  int i;
  double val;
  printf ("Floats passed: ");
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,amount);
  for (i=0;i<amount;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,double);
    printf ("\t%.2f",val);
  }
  va_end(vl);
  printf ("\n");
}

int main ()
{
  PrintFloats (3,3.14159,2.71828,1.41421);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice that PrintFloats here requires that you pass in the number of additional arguments. printf doesn't need to do this, because it can infer how many arguments you are passing in by counting the tags in the format string.

Answer (score 5):

printf is a "variadic" function. This means that the argument list is declared with `...` on the end, and in the implementation of printf the `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg` etc macros are used to extract the arguments from the variable length list.

Comment: (Also, technically, the argument list is not infinite - it's limited by the stack size.)

Answer (score -3):

The keyword is variadic arguments, and they are declared with ...

Comment: Are you planning to complete this or should we go ahead and downvote as it doesn't really answer the Question convincingly.

Comment: It is complete, please feel free to downvote. I think that there are plenty of explanations in the web for the keywords variadic arguments and that they need not be repeated here - this is why I kept my answer short.

Comment: -1 If the argument for posting an Incomplete answer is `plenty of explanations available on the web` then one should not bother to answer.If one cares to post an answer it better be correct and complete.

Comment: I respect your opinion about that, but differ about the completeness. By the way, I hope you are not taking the terminal "..." of my answer as an ellipsis, they reference the ... in "void foo(...)".

Comment: Since you feel the need to provide an explanation about what `...` stand for in your answer it provides a testimonial to the **completeness** of it.